# excel find string and then IF statement it

Tags: excel, vba

I have basically inherited a database within which the data is pretty messed up. I need to start cleansing it which I am doing in Excel.

The data has a code which has then been used within the other cells when it should not have. Basically I want to write some VB which will look at 
`CellB` and compare the first section of text between `[ and .` with the text found in `CellA`.

If they are the same i want it to remove the text from `CellB` if it is not I want it to just leave `CellB` as is.

The example below is the simplest I need to do this in loads of columns that have loads of different sections of text the only constant is that the code I need to check will be between the first `[ and .` in all columns.

I have tried writing some VB using `MID` statement but can’t get the hang of it.

Any ideas?

```
Before
A            B
M548    [M548.PLANNED]
M513    [M503.PLANNED]
M503    [M503.PLANNED]

After
A            B
M548    [.PLANNED]
M513    [M503.PLANNED]
M503    [.PLANNED]
```

Comment: A simple solution involves using Find & Replace to remove the "[", Text to Columns delimited by a ".", then compare the two strings to see if they match.  Then you can concatenate it back together.

Comment: 1) Welcome to SO 2) Is this really related to `vb.net`. If not, remove the tag 3) formula to extract the data between `[` and `.` is `=MID(B2,2,FIND(".",B2)-2)` 4) Lastly, if you need help with actual VBA, you're going to need to show your efforts so far and where they are failing. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry Removed VB.net that was a suggested tag, I just saw the VB and clicked sorry.

Comment: Currently I am failing at the first hurdle I had written slightly different code '=MID(B2,"[",,Find(".",B2)-2)' Which had not worked.

Answer (score 2):

If every piece of column B's data is in that format, this could work:

```
=IF(MID(B4,2,4)=A4,"[.PLANNED]",B4)
```

Here's a picture for added clarification:

[image: Image Link 1]

You would then 'Paste Values' into the second column to replace the current data.

Comment: Thanks so much I think i can make this one work for all my other columns. Thanks again

Comment: Voted up for the effort! ;)

Comment: You might want to allow for a different length of data in `A4` - changing the formula to `=IF(MID(B4,2,LEN(A4))=A4,"[.PLANNED]",B4)` allows for a variable length of `A4`.

Comment: I was just going to ask that. THanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in the same exact format, as in [ followed by 4 characters you can just use the following formula in a Column C.

```
=IF(MID(B2,2,4)=A2,CONCATENATE("[",MID(B2,SEARCH(".",B2),100)),B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple replace would work if the value in A only occurs once in B:

```
Sub cleanData()
    For i = 1 To 3
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 2).Value, Cells(i, 1).Value, "")
    Next
End Sub
```